# Spawn a process from Rhozet Carbon Coder

Tags: spawn

I am trying to figure out how to spawn a process / start an EXE from Rhozet Carbon Coder.
The [manual](http://www.rhozet.com/carbon_apiManual.pdf) mentions a task that sounds promising, "ExternalProcess", in section 5.8.2 but does not document this task.
Has anybody had success doing this, or knows where the ExternalProcess task is documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have heard back from Rhozet that the ExternalProcess command mentioned tangentially in the manual is a typo, there isn't any task by that name.
Currently the only way to launch a process is to use the Notify task.
For example the folowing xml put in the Sources section of a configuration file launches notepad before running the job.

```
  <Notify>
    <PreTaskNotify>
      <ProcessNotify_0 NotifyCommand="notepad.exe" />
    </PostTaskNotify>
  </Notify>
```